# Exporting p12 certificate with openssl tool

Tags: openssl, key, pkcs#12

I have created a bat file for generating p12 file with my tomcat certificate. Last time I use it was few months ago and it worked. Recently I tried to generate the p12 file, it shown "No certificate matches private key" and the p12 file could not be generated.

Here's the command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in new_cert\server.crt -inkey new_cert\server.key -out new_cert\server.p12 -name %TargetHostName% -CAfile ca_bundle.crt -caname root -passin pass:%jdkKeyStorePassword% -passout pass:%jdkKeyStorePassword%
```

Is that anything wrong with my command syntax causing the error ?

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that your input certificate and private key don't correspond to each other. You can check it easily:

```
openssl x509 –noout –modulus -in new_cert\server.crt | openssl md5
```

and

```
openssl rsa –noout –modulus -in new_cert\server.key | openssl md5
```

should be the same.